# Journey Builder Code Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I need to execute a Server-Side JavaScript activity inside a Journey. If I remember well, there is a new activity called "Code Activity" that could be used for this. I am not sure if still in Beta or already released. Does anyone knows if "Code Activity" is already released ?

Answer (score 2):

Code Activity is not released, neither there is an estimated release date. New features are usually announced very close to each Marketing Cloud release, and there is also no guarantee that features provided to a limited audience/as beta, will make it into production.

Comment: Thanks for the update Lukas.